# How do I test a function that returns an observable using timed intervals in rxjs 5?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

For example, I have a function like this:

```
export function timeRange(start: number, end: number): Rx.Observable<number> {
  return Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
  .map(n => n + start)
  .take(end - start + 1)
}
```

And I had a unit test that ran timeRange(10, 100) and asserted values against it.

The problem is the time intervals would make my test too long to run.

How would you reduce the time interval without touching the function itself?

I tried reading the docs on schedulers but I didn't get it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There're a couple of caveats but you can test your function as follows:

```js
const Rx = require('rxjs');
const chai = require('chai');

function timeRange(start, end, interval = 1000, scheduler = Rx.Scheduler.async) {
  return Rx.Observable.interval(interval, scheduler)
    .map(n => n + start)
    .take(end - start + 1)
}

let scheduler = new Rx.TestScheduler(chai.assert.deepEqual);
let source = timeRange(2, 8, 50, scheduler);
let values = {'2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8};
scheduler.expectObservable(source).toBe('-----2----3----4----5----6----7----(8|)', values);

scheduler.flush();
```

A few points to notice:

- The function takes four arguments now. The interval and the `Scheduler` that we need to use to pass the `TestScheduler`.
- The `TestScheduler` needs to get a method to deep compare objects. It'll be used to compare arrays of `Notification` objects.
- You can't use `1000` because maximum time allowed is [hardcoded as 750](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/testing/TestScheduler.ts#L10). Note, that this is just virtual time and is unrelated to real time so `50` we're using in this test isn't the same as `50ms`. We just need to fit inside that `750` time frame.
- Then marble tests as typical marble test. See https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/writing-marble-tests.md for more information. Just be aware that I can't use the same global `mocha` functions as the default RxJS operators.
- I had to specify also the values because marble tests by default use strings and I need to force integers to ensure deep equality.

You can test that this fails by changing one marble value:

```js
let values = {'2': 42, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8};
```

Also, you can see what the notification objects are by printing them to console:

```js
let scheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
   console.log('Actual:', actual, '\n\n', 'Expected:', expected);
   chai.assert.deepEqual(actual, expected);
});
```

**Using RxJS 5 `mocha` helpers**

At this moment RxJS 5 doesn't expose the `mocha` testing helpers. I'm actually using it in another project I'm working on right now (including generating diagram images). You can have a look here https://github.com/martinsik/rxjs-extra into `package.json` what scripts I'm using. It works well but the setup is a little hard to understand. It involves downloading the RxJS 5 archive, copying a few files and patching it with a [couple of files](https://github.com/martinsik/rxjs-plus/tree/master/spec-patch). Then the default options for `mocha` test are set with [`mocha.opts`](https://github.com/martinsik/rxjs-plus/blob/master/test/mocha.opts) that is based on the original from RxJS 5.

Answer (score 3):

You create either a `TestScheduler` or `VirtualTimeScheduler` and pass it as the optional second argument to [`Observable.Interval`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/interval.md). In your case you'd simply add an optional scheduler argument to `timeRange` and pass the value on.

These test schedulers allow you to "pass time" without waiting for actual time to elapse.

For more information and examples, see [Testing your Rx Application](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/testing.md)

Comment: Sorry I should clarify.  I'm using rxjs 5.  Do you know the rxjs 5 equivalent?  The links you provided are for rxjs 4.

Comment: There aren't updated docs but the types are still there. Eg. `import {TestScheduler} from 'rxjs/testing/TestScheduler'`

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem recently and discovered [**marble testing**](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/writing-marble-tests.md) which lets you write awesome visual tests that make timed Observable testing extremely easy.

Marble testing abstracts time away and the tests run instantly (by using TestScheduler under the hood), but you still can test complex timed processes. This is an example test to give you an idea of the syntax:

```
it('should set up an interval', () => {
  const expected = '----------0---------1---------2---------3---------4---------5---------6-----';
  expectObservable(Observable.interval(100, rxTestScheduler)).toBe(expected, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
});
```

This actually is the official unit test from for `Observable.interval` from the rxjs5 repo: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/spec/observables/interval-spec.ts

Check out the [official documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/writing-marble-tests.md) for more info.

Getting it running was a bit of a challenge, but all you basically need are the two files `marble-testing.ts` and `test-helper.ts` from this [marble testing example project](https://github.com/btroncone/rxjs-marble-testing).

Answer (score 0):

This worked great for me: [rxjs-testscheduler-compat](https://github.com/kwonoj/rxjs-testscheduler-compat).  From the README:

> rxjs-testscheduler-compat provides RxJS v4's test scheduler interface to v5 version of RxJS allows to migrate existing test cases with minimum effort as well as writing new test cases for certain cases.