# How do I unit test RxJS5 when using promises?

Tags: rxjs5

This question is about RxJS5.

Context: I tried using TestScheduler, it all works fine until I plug in the promises.

For instance let's take "someFunction" from the example below. How would I validate the output expected within 1 minute period (without actually having to wait 1 minute in the test).

```
const asyncFunction = new Promise( (resolve) =>
   setTimeout((() => resolve(1)), 0)
);

const someFunction = () =>
  Rx.Observable.fromInterval(15000)
    .flatMap( each => Rx.Observable.from(asyncFunction()))
    .map(each => each + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer sums up basically everything you need to know: [How do I test a function that returns an observable using timed intervals in rxjs 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42732988/how-do-i-test-a-function-that-returns-an-observable-using-timed-intervals-in-rxj/42734681#42734681)

Simply said, you should allow the user to set custom delay even thought the default value can be `15000`:

```
const someFunction = (delay = 15000) =>
  Rx.Observable.fromInterval(delay)
  ...
```

Then for the `TestSheduler` you need to use delay `<= 750` because 750 is hardcoded as the maximum virtual time. See the answer linked above for more details.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful piece of information, since I did have problems with longer delays! However linked answer doesn't mention promises and in my situation, even with low delays, tests do not work with observables based on promises.