# Angular2 / RxJS / Jasmine : How to test Observable chain/sequence (operators)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, rxjs, observable

As part of an Angular 4 project, I am desperately trying to test with Jasmine a function which implement an RxJs chain/sequence with operators (`map` in my case).

```js
class RendezVousResolver {

  searchRendezVous(code: string): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      this.userCardService.readCard(code).map(userData => {
        this.rendezVousService.search(userData).subscribe(
          result => {
            observer.next(result);
          },
          error => {
            observer.error(error);
          }
        );
      });
    });
  }

}
```

My unit test uses 2 mocks in order to "simulate" the 2 services' layers: `userCardService` and `rendezVousService`.

```js
class MockUserCardService {

  readCard(code: string): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.of('<data></data>');
  }

}

class MockRendezVousService {

  search(userData : string): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.of({
      rdvs: []
    });
  }

}

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      RendezVousResolver,
      { provide: RendezVousService, useClass: MockRendezVousService },
      { provide: SwcVitaleReadingService, useClass: MockSwcVitaleReadingService }
    ]
  });
  fixture = TestBed.get(RendezVousResolver);
});
```

And here my unit test.

```js
it('should return the expected response', async(() => {
  fixture.resolve(undefined, undefined).subscribe(
    rdvs => {
      console.log("expect");
      expect(rdvs).toEqual({
        rdvs: []
      });
    },
    error => {
      console.log("fail");
      fail('No error was expected');
    }
  );
}));
```

When I execute it, the test seems to not wait for the events emitted by the mocked Observable. Neither the `expected` nor the `fail` are executed. I'm sure about that because nothing is logged in the console.

The only way I found to make this test passed is to not use the operator `map` and replace my code with nested subscriptions.

```js
searchRendezVous(code: string): Observable<any> {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    this.userCardService.readCard(code).subscribe(
      userData => {
        this.rendezVousService.search(userData).subscribe(
          rdvs => {
            observer.next(rdvs);
          },
          error => {
            observer.error(error);
          }
        )
      },
      error => {
        observer.error(error);
      }
    );
  });
}
```

I encountered the same problem with others operators than `map` (`zip` for example).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have  a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42732988/how-do-i-test-a-function-that-returns-an-observable-using-timed-intervals-in-rxj/42734681#42734681

Comment: Unrelated to testing, but those calls you are making to `Observable.create` are something of an antipattern. You might want to consider watching the following: https://egghead.io/courses/save-time-avoiding-common-mistakes-using-rxjs

Comment: the easiest way when you have many async operations is to use the done function, look for jasmine.done on this page https://angular.io/guide/testing

Comment: in both the mock classes return some data instead of an `empty object`

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your `RendezVousResolver` by swapping `Observable.create` for existing behaviour / functions in RxJs:

```js
class RendezVousResolver {
  searchRendezVous(code: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.userCardService.readCard(code)
      .mergeMap(userData => this.rendezVousService.search(userData));
  }
}
```

That way you have less edge cases to catch yourself.

Testing this can be done without time by swapping the `readCard` and `search` with mocks returning a `Rx.Observable.from([])` with the expected mock data. Simply invoking `.toPromise()` on your `searchRendezVous()` will make that work without any scheduler magic.

```js
it('returns data', () => {
  return searchRendezVous('foo')
    .toPromise()
    .then(searchResults => {
      expect(searchResults).to.not.be.empty();//assert what you need
    })
});
```