# How to test a complex observable chain?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angularfire2

I have a angularfire2 function that I'd like to test.  The issue I'm running into is I have no idea how to mock the anonymous function call made by `this.db.collection()` let along how to mock the piped functions.   I'd like to test what value was passed to the ref.orderBy function, and the results returned by the pipe. How would I got about doing this?

```
   sortedList(collection, orderByProperty){
      return this.db.collection(collection, ref => {
          return ref.orderBy(orderByProperty, 'asc')
        })
        .snapshotChanges().pipe(
            map(actions => actions.map(a => {
              const data = a.payload.doc.data();
              const id = a.payload.doc.id;
              return { id, ...data };
            }))
          );
    }
```

..

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { of } from "rxjs";
import { FirebaseService } from './firebase.service';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

describe('FirebaseService', () => {

  let service: FirebaseService;
  const mockedData = [{
    payload:{
      doc:{
        id:"zyx",
        data:()=>{
          return {hello:"world"}
        }
      }
    },

  },{
    payload:{
      doc:{
        id:"abc",
        data:()=>{
          return {hello:"goodbye"}
        }
      }
    }
  }]


var afSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('AngularFirestore', ['collection', 'snapshotChanges', 'pipe']);
afSpy.collection.and.returnValue(afSpy);
afSpy.snapshotChanges.and.returnValue(afSpy); 
afSpy.pipe.and.returnValue(of(mockedData))


  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers:[
        { provide: AngularFirestore, useValue: afSpy }
      ],      
    })
    service = TestBed.get(FirebaseService); //get the testbed and set it so we can use it in our functions
  });
it('should return a sorted list', () => {
  service.sortedList('fakeCollection', 'id').subscribe(res=>{
    expect(res).toEqual([{hello:"world", id:"zyx"}, {hello:"goodbye", id:"abc"}])
  })
  expect(afSpy.pipe).toHaveBeenCalled();

});


});
```

......................................................................................

Comment: You are not giving any hints really on what types you are using(e.g. actions) but if it's about testing different states in the observable chain you can use [Marble testing](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-marbles)

Comment: updated my answer.

Comment: Here's a good example on how [marble test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42732988/how-do-i-test-a-function-that-returns-an-observable-using-timed-intervals-in-rxj/42734681#42734681) look like in the familar scenario as you want to test it (in rxjs5 so you have to adjust to rxjs6)

Comment: Did the answer below help you?

Answer (score 0):

Justin, this looks familiar!  :)

I set this problem up in a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53732604?file=app%2Ffirebase.service.spec.ts) similar to the last problem.  This time I made an effort to change as little of your code as possible, keeping what I hope was your basic structure.  Below is the `describe()` that I came up with.  All the details in the Stackblitz.

I also had to add FirebaseService to the providers array of the TestBed to get the spec to run without error.

It looks like `snapshotChanges()` returns the Observable this time, so I nested the `insideCollection` spyObject as the return value of the `collection()` method, then set the return value of `snapshotChanges()` to an Observable of your mockData array using `of()`.

As you can see in the Stackblitz, your `it()` spec runs just fine just as you originally wrote it without modification.

```
describe('FirebaseService', () => {

  let service: FirebaseService;
  const mockedData = [{
    payload:{
      doc:{
        id:"zyx",
        data:()=>{
          return {hello:"world"}
        }
      }
    },

  },{
    payload:{
      doc:{
        id:"abc",
        data:()=>{
          return {hello:"goodbye"}
        }
      }
    }
  }]
  var insideCollection = jasmine.createSpyObj('collection', ['snapshotChanges']);
  var afSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('AngularFirestore', ['collection']);
  afSpy.collection.and.returnValue(insideCollection);
  insideCollection.snapshotChanges.and.returnValue(of(mockedData));
  // afSpy.pipe.and.returnValue(of(mockedData)) <-- .pipe is already a method on an Observable, no need for this.


    beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers:[
          FirebaseService,
          { provide: AngularFirestore, useValue: afSpy }
        ]
      })
      service = TestBed.get(FirebaseService); //get the testbed and set it so we can use it in our functions
    });

  it('should return a sorted list', () => {
    service.sortedList('fakeCollection', 'id').subscribe(res=>{
      expect(res).toEqual([{hello:"world", id:"zyx"}, {hello:"goodbye", id:"abc"}])
    })
    expect(insideCollection.snapshotChanges).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });


});
```

I hope this helps.  :)